# Kivy Python Functions Classes and Clock Stuff

Tags: python, kivy

This is mostly me not grasping object oriented programming, but involving the clock function

I want my GUI to have a button that starts a constantly updating function (scheduled using the clock function). And also want that GUI to have a button that ends the constantly updating function. (or is there a better way to accomplish this? put it in an if statement? boolean that changes when I press that button, would that value update on the python side?)

```py
import kivy
import sqlite3
import sched, time
import smbus
import time
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js
import os
import signal
import multiprocessing, signal
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, WipeTransition, SwapTransition

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04

p = multiprocessing.Process(target = muterun_js,args=('iss_telemetry.js',)) #might delete this

conn = sqlite3.connect('iss_telemetry.db') #sqlite database call change to include directory
c = conn.cursor() 
val = ""

def StringToBytes(val):
    retVal = []
    for c in val:
            retVal.append(ord(c))
    return retVal

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class CalibrateScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ManualControlScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ManualControlScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def i2cWrite(self, *args):
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0, StringToBytes(*args))

class MimicScreen(Screen, EventDispatcher):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MimicScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyButton(Button):
    pass

def point_inside_polygon(x, y, poly):
    ...

class TriangleButton(ButtonBehavior, Widget):
    ...

class MainApp(App):

    event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 1)
    event()
    event.cancel()

    def build(self):
        self.mimic_screen = MimicScreen(name = 'mimic')
        root = ScreenManager(transition=WipeTransition())
        root.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'main'))
        root.add_widget(CalibrateScreen(name = 'calibrate'))
        root.add_widget(self.mimic_screen)
        root.add_widget(ManualControlScreen(name = 'manualcontrol'))
        root.current= 'main'

       # Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 1)
        return root

    def clockStart(self):
        event()

    def clockEnd(self):
        event.cancel()   

    def i2cWrite(self, *args):
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0, StringToBytes(*args))

    def update_labels(self, dt):
        c.execute('select two from telemetry')
        values = c.fetchall()
        psarj = values[0]
        ssarj = values[1]
        ptrrj = values[2]
        strrj = values[3]
        beta1b = values[4]
        beta1a = values[5]
        beta2b = values[6]
        beta2a = values[7]
        beta3b = values[8]
        beta3a = values[9]
        beta4b = values[10]
        beta4a = values[11]
        aos = values[12]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.psarjvalue.text = str(psarj[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.ssarjvalue.text = str(ssarj[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.ptrrjvalue.text = str(ptrrj[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.strrjvalue.text = str(strrj[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta1bvalue.text = str(beta1b[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta1avalue.text = str(beta1a[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta2bvalue.text = str(beta2b[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta2avalue.text = str(beta2a[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta3bvalue.text = str(beta3b[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta3avalue.text = str(beta3a[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta4bvalue.text = str(beta4b[0])[:-5]
        self.mimic_screen.ids.beta4avalue.text = str(beta4a[0])[:-5]



Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.8
#:import kivy kivy
#:import win kivy.core.window
<MainScreen>:
    ...
<ManualControlScreen>:
    ...     
<CalibrateScreen>:
    ...
<MimicScreen>:
    name: 'mimic'
    FloatLayout:
        psarjvalue: psarjvalue
        id: mimicscreenlayout
        Image:
            source: 'iss1.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        ...
        Button:
            id: mimicstartbutton
            size_hint: 0.25,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.07, "y": 0.6}
            text: 'MIMIC'
            disabled: False
            font_size: 30
            on_release: telemetrystatus.text = 'Sending Telemetry...'
            on_release: app.clockStart()
            on_release: mimicstopbutton.disabled = False
            on_release: mimicstartbutton.disabled = True
        Button:
            id: mimicstopbutton
            size_hint: 0.25,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.07, "y": 0.4}
            text: 'Stop'
            disabled: True
            font_size: 30
            on_release: telemetrystatus.text = 'I2C Stopped'
            on_release: app.clockStop()
            on_release: mimicstopbutton.disabled = True
            on_release: mimicstartbutton.disabled = False
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.3,0.1
            pos_hint: {"Left": 1, "Bottom": 1}
            text: 'Return'
            font_size: 30
            on_release: app.clockStop()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'

<TriangleButton>:
    ...

''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Here's the relevant class:

```py
class MainApp(App):

    event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 1)
    event()
    event.cancel()

    def build(self):
        self.mimic_screen = MimicScreen(name = 'mimic')
        root = ScreenManager(transition=WipeTransition())
        root.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'main'))
        root.add_widget(CalibrateScreen(name = 'calibrate'))
        root.add_widget(self.mimic_screen)
        root.add_widget(ManualControlScreen(name = 'manualcontrol'))
        root.current= 'main'

       # Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 1)
        return root

    def clockStart(root):
        event()

    def clockEnd(root):
        event.cancel()   

    def i2cWrite(self, *args):
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0, StringToBytes(*args))

    def update_labels(self, dt):
        ...
```

And here's the relevant part of the kv code (reduced)

```py
<MimicScreen>:
    name: 'mimic'
    FloatLayout:
        ...
        Button:
            ...
            on_release: app.clockStart()
        Button:
            ...
            on_release: app.clockStop()
        Button:
            ...
            on_release: app.clockStop()
```

So when I try to run it like this it complains about not knowing what event is. I was under the impressing that declaring it outside the class functions would make it available to the whole class.

Suggestions? Advice? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining because you need to define a variable as global to use it inside a function you haven't passed it into or attach it to the object with `self.varname`. Moreover, you're creating the event and then cancelling it right away before build has been called.

You should have a button that has a method `on_release` that starts a `schedule_interval` functional call with `Clock`.  This button should become disabled after being pressed.  Your second button will then unschedule using `cancel`.

Here's a basic working example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class StartButton(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        self.event_handle = Clock.schedule_interval(self.clocks_are_fun,0.5)
        self.disabled = True
    def clocks_are_fun(self,dt):
        self.parent.parent.ids.mylabel.text = 'Frames: ' + str(Clock.frames)
    def closing_time(self):
        self.event_handle.cancel()

class StopButton(Button):
    def on_release(self):
        self.parent.parent.ids.button1.closing_time()
        self.parent.parent.ids.button1.disabled = False

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        boxyFunTime = MyLayout()
        return boxyFunTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And the .kv file:

```
<MyLayout>:
    id: mylayoutid
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        StartButton:
            text: 'start'
            id: button1
        StopButton:
            text: 'stop'
            id: button2
    Label:
        id: mylabel
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great, my only issue now is that I'm trying to call my update_values function in the MainApp class from that clock scheduler, which is complaining about arguments. Call is Clock.schedule_interval(MainApp,update_labels(), 1). It complains about unbound method must be called with MainApp instance, is that not what I'm doing already? (I don't want to move the update_labels function from MainApp because it handles a lot of children widgets that I don't fully understand how to update across classes). Any thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't really be using that method within your main app instance.  Your main app instance should just be used to return the widget tree that you've constructed.  Place all the function calls in your widget tree.  Might be a pain to move things but it will be easier to work with.